# How to dynamically display image with style background in ejs

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

How do I display an image with style and background-image in ejs template

This is working:

```
<a href="blog-single.html" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('images/image_1.jpg');"></a>
```

But this is not working:

```
<a href="blog-single.html" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('<%=event.eventImage %>' )"></a>
```

this is my full code

```
<div class="row d-flex">
    <% upcoming_events.forEach(event=> { %>
      <div class="col-lg-4 ftco-animate">
        <div class="blog-entry">
          <a href="blog-single.html" class="block-20" style="background-image: url('<%=event.eventImage %>' )">
          </a>
          <div class="text d-block">
            <div class="meta">
              <p>
                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-calendar mr-2"></span>Sept. 06, 2020</a>
                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-user mr-2"></span>Admin</a>
                <a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="fa fa-comment mr-2"></span> 3</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="heading"><a href="#">Best for any industrial &amp; business solution</a></h3>
            <p><a href="blog.html" class="btn btn-secondary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%}) ;%>
  </div>
```

Note, when I inspect it on the browser it shows the `AWS` image `URL` correctly but the image does not show.

Comment: Does there need to be a space after the `=`? In other words `<%= event.eventImage %>`?

Comment: @Sean space isn't the problem, I removed the space but it still doesn't show. Thanks

Comment: check the networks tab in chrome to see if the image loads correctly, or attempts to load at all

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I was the cause of the problem, I did not add the CSS that is supposed to load the image, I later discovered that, and it's working now.